# Calling a method from Main Form to run on Child Form / Threads

Tags: c#, lightningchart

I am using WinForms C# .NET 4.6

I have 3 Forms. Main, Form1 and Form2 Each form is running on a different thread.
Form1 and Form2 have Arction LightningChart Control.. Each of those Forms has a method called "PlotUpdate" to update the charts with random values.

The Main Form has a timer that is triggered every 100ms. I want to call PlotUpdate from the Main Timer tick event to update the charts on Form1 and Form2. PlotUpdate method works in case the Arction LightningChart Control is placed in the Main Form, otherwise it doesn't.

How can I achieve this?

**MainForm.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MultipleUIThreads
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        const int FormSeriesCount = 3;
        static System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myTimer.Interval = 100;
            myTimer.Tick += myTimer_Tick;
            myTimer.Start();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Start new UI thread for Form3
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Form1 f1 = new Form1();
                Application.Run(f1);
            });
            thread1.Start();

            // Start new UI thread for Form2
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Form2 f2 = new Form2(); 
                Application.Run(f2);
            });
            thread2.Start();

        }

        private void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //What shall I write here
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs / Form2.cs are alike**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Arction.WinForms.Charting;

namespace MultipleUIThreads
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        int _pointsAdded = 0;
        Random _rand = new Random();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ChartCreator.InitChart(LChart);

        }

        public void PlotUpdate()
        {
            LChart.BeginUpdate();

            double x = _pointsAdded * 0.1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                SeriesPoint[] points = new SeriesPoint[1];
                points[0].X = x;
                points[0].Y = _rand.Next(-100, 100);
                LChart.ViewXY.PointLineSeries[i].AddPoints(points, false);
            }

            LChart.ViewXY.XAxes[0].ScrollPosition = x;
            LChart.EndUpdate();

            _pointsAdded++;
        }
    }
}
```

**ChartCreator.cs**

```
using Arction.WinForms.Charting;
using Arction.WinForms.Charting.Axes;
using Arction.WinForms.Charting.SeriesXY;
using Arction.WinForms.Charting.Views.ViewXY;

namespace MultipleUIThreads
{
     class ChartCreator
    {
        public static void InitChart(LightningChartUltimate ulChart)
        {
            ulChart.BeginUpdate();
            ViewXY view = ulChart.ViewXY;

            AxisX xAxis = view.XAxes[0];
            xAxis.SetRange(0, 20);
            xAxis.ScrollMode = XAxisScrollMode.Scrolling;

            view.YAxes.Clear();

            for (int seriesIndex = 0; seriesIndex < 1; seriesIndex++)
            {
                AxisY yAxis = new AxisY(view);
                yAxis.SetRange(-100, 100);
                view.YAxes.Add(yAxis);

                PointLineSeries line = new PointLineSeries(view, xAxis, yAxis);
                line.PointsVisible = false;
                line.LineStyle.Color = DefaultColors.SeriesForBlackBackground[seriesIndex];
                view.PointLineSeries.Add(line);
            }

            view.DropOldSeriesData = true;
            view.AxisLayout.YAxesLayout = YAxesLayout.Stacked;


            ulChart.EndUpdate();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seemingly, Its the way you are opening your forms that are getting you, there is no need to run the forms in different threads and call `Application.Run`. Just create the form, and call `ShowDialog`

Comment: @TheGeneral, Well, I want to run the forms on different threads because, the rendering later on will be intense to be run on the same UI Thread. Using ShowDialog() only without creating a new thread will run all the forms on the same thread afterall. This is what I want to avoid

Comment: Well that makes more sense. Well your first problem is the scope of your forms `Form1 f1 = new Form1();` you will need to store them globally (as instance members)

Comment: Edited That. What else?

Comment: "The Main Form has a timer that is triggered every 100ms. I want to call PlotUpdate from the Main Timer tick event to update the charts on Form1 and Form2."  Why not just pop a Timer on Form1 and Form2 and have it update itself?  Then you don't need to worry about the fact that they are all running in different threads...

Answer (score 0):

You on the right track. The code

```
            // Start new UI thread for Form3
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            Application.Run(f1);
        });
        thread1.Start();
```

will create for you a Windows Form running on its own Thread. Just don't  forget that UI threads should run as AppartmentState.STA. Therefore, include line `thread1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);`
That is not the only way to create [Multiple UI threads in WinForms](http://dotnetbeyond.blogspot.com/2011/10/multiple-ui-threads-in-winforms.html).

Now about LightningChart Control/component. LightningChart(R) .NET should be updated in the Main Thread, as for the most UI controls. When using a another (background) thread in the application, all UI updates from the thread must go through Invoke (Control.Invoke() in WinForms).
There is already WPF solution [Multiple LightningChart and multiple UI threads](https://www.arction.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=336). Your WinForms application should/could follow very similar logic.
The first thing you need is the list of Charts you are planning to manipulate/access later. Second, don't forget that Chart.Parent should be set, which is the Form itself or Panel in that form. Finally you call you call Chart.Invoke() for each LightningChart instance you want to update in Tick handler. For example,

```
    private void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(_chartContainers.Count == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _chartForms.Count; i++)
            {
                //ChartWindow cw = new ChartWindow(_chartForms[i]);
                _chartForms[i].Invoke((System.Action)delegate 
                {
                    ChartWindow cw = new ChartWindow(_chartForms[i]);
                    _chartContainers.Add(cw);
                });

            }
        }

        if (_chartForms.Count == 0)
            return;

        for (int iChart = 0; iChart < _chartForms.Count; iChart++)
        {
            ChartWindow cw = _chartContainers[iChart];
            cw.Chart.Invoke((System.Action)delegate 
            {
                cw.AddSeriesPoints(new double[] { random.NextDouble()*10 });
            });
        }
    }
```

The first part is actually uses (empty) Form's thread to create ChartWindow (basically creates Chart and set the parent to particular Form) inside it.

The second part adds new random point to each Chart. There, *AddSeriesPoints* custom method defined in ChartWindow class to add points array and scroll. You can use LightningChart methods directly as well.